# Invoked Global Function and can't return defined variables

Tags: javascript, function, variables

This is my code

```
<script id="candidateCode">

    getCar(); //Invokes global func getCar
    getCar(); //Invoked global func getCar

    var myDreamCar = getDreamCar();

    var firstCar = { make: "Honda", model: "Accord" };
    var anotherCar = { make: "Honda", model: "Civic" };

    function getYear() {
        return 2019;
    };

    function getCity() {
        return "Laguna Beach";
    };

    function getTruck() {
        return myTruck;
    };

</script>
```

In this exercise, I am being asked to first invoke a global predefined function "getCar" and so far I have passed all steps of the exercise besides the following.

I for some reason, cannot figure out for the LIFE OF ME, how to assign the variable firstCar and anotherCar to the function getCar().

Is this a scope issue? Can anyone help? I've invoked the function twice, but I find it impossible to assign the return value to variables I have declared above?

Any insight? THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

My instructions are:

1 - There is a global function defined for you named getCar. Invoke this function 2 times.

2 - When you invoke the function getCar assign the return value to variables declared with the var keyword and use the following names:
firstCar
anotherCar

3- There is a global function defined for you named getDreamCar. Invoke this function 1 time and assign value to a variable named myDreamCar.

Comment: I think the questions are just poorly worded. I think it means your 2 calls in step 1 should be set to the values in step 2. ie: `var firstCar = getCar();` and so on.

Comment: Jesus lol, thank you! I spent literally 6 hours last night trying to figure out why the debugger kept giving me an error... all while I'm reading the instructions as step by step verbatim instructions. Wish the instructions were worded better... thank you, literally fixed my issues in 10 seconds... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign the return value of a function to a variable, you assign the function invocation to the variable just like you did in *myDreamCar*

```html
<script id="candidateCode">

   var firstCar = getCar(); //Invokes global func getCar and assigns the return value to firstCar
   var anotherCar = getCar(); //Invokes global func getCar and assigns the return value to anotherCar

   var myDreamCar = getDreamCar();

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I thought but the debugger had me going crazy and the question was worded in a very weird way. Thank you all for the clarity, saved me tons of time!